# Problem with 'man -k ^' causing severe slowdown

Tags: macos, performance, shell, time, emacs

This begun with me seeing that my emacs `man-mode` was suspiciously slow, and I found that emacs was invoking `man -k ^` and `man -k^[number]` on the command-line whenever I type `M-x man RET [number]` . The timing and wc output is kind of ridiculous:

```
% time man -k ^ | wc 
makewhatis: /Library/TeX/texbin/man: Not a directory
   12434  101864  923700
man -k ^  0.67s user 1.40s system 103% cpu 1.991 total
wc  0.01s user 0.02s system 1% cpu 1.990 total
```

Why is it that the total time is nearly 2 seconds when it seems the operation took about ~0.03 seconds? I believe this may be what is causing a severe slowdown, and I'd like to get to the bottom of this bloat in my system. MacOS Ventura.

Comment: The preceding reddit post with more information: https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/12vjw05/easiest_way_to_browse_man_pages_within_emacs/

Comment: Well, as you know from `man man`, a `man -k SOMETHING` is equivalent to `apropos SOMETHING`, and `apropos ^`  takes `^` as regular expression. No wonder that you get so many matches and that this takes its time ....

Comment: Out of interest... what numbers do you get from these?: `man -k ^ | wc -l` and `manpath | sed 's/:/\n/g' | wc -l` (my numbers are 6840 and 5 respectively, and I'm getting a dramatically faster response than you, so I'm just wondering whether your numbers are dramatically larger than mine.  I also have a SSD hard drive; a spinning disk would undoubtedly be slower here.

Comment: `12434` for the first with noticeable lag and `7` for the second. I'm on a Macbook Pro, so I believe it is SSD.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That doesn't come close to explaining the speed difference, so I guess it's something else.

Comment: yea, I get 12k for the first one, but it only takes a fraction of a second (~0.03), also ssd.  Could it be something related to mac vs linux?

Comment: We seem to be getting similar user and system times, but I'm not sure why my total is so much higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand what you are looking at.

`man -k ^3` will search the entire `man` database for every manual page whose abstract begins with `3` (there are none). `man -k ^` will simply output all abstracts. This is a moderately expensive operation, especially if `man` needs to rebuild its indices behind the scenes. However, the main part of the processing is in waiting for the disk while reading and possibly writing the indices, and buffering the output it writes, so it does not consume a lot of CPU in the end.

Your `time` output for `wc` obviously only accounts for the time it took to process the output from `man`, which is trivial.

You are apparently using Zsh, which does not include the "real" time in the `time` output. On my system, after running `man -k ^` repeatedly, the entire process takes on the order of 10 seconds, but out of that, it only consumes about 5s of CPU time (0.8s user + 4s system).

Ultimately, we have to ask why you enter a number after `M-x man` and what you hope to accomplish eventually. If you really want a list of all installed man pages, or all man pages in a particular section, it is going to take a while.

(On my system, `M-x man <RET> 3 <RET>` only outputs some internal junk which looks like `man` internal shell scripts, reformatted.)

Comment: The goal of `M-x man <RET> 2 read <RET>` for example is to get the equivalent of `man 2 read` on the command-line. It works eventually, but of course, it is slow. Eventually, I got this to work by giving advice to `man` in emacs, so I guess the underlying question is why emacs feels the need to invoke both `-k ^2` and `-k ^` whenever I enter a space after a number ... `M-x man <RET> [0-9] ` ... and hang, without showing any more input (though it receives it) in the minibuffer.

Comment: Looks like you have fallen into an unfortunate corner case, where it probably tries to be efficient, but instead spends a lot of time on unnecessary "optimization". I would expect a modern (heh) Emacs command to allow something like C-u 2 M-x man read but ... this one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`man -k ^` takes about 0.08s on my Debian machine.  Apparently macOS makes no effort to cache the index, so the command is ridiculously slow.  Is there something comparable to `mandb` on macOS to speed this up?